# Pandas to flatten nested JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following JSON and using json_normalize to flatten nested array.

It works, but the results outputs 4 records (tickets) instead of the initial 2.

Input JSON file (2 tickets with 2 nested custom_fields):

```
[
    {
        "ticket_id": 15177,
        "status": "solved",
        "custom_fields": [
            {
                "id": 360015283851,
                "value": "severity_2"
            },
            {
                "id": 360016758872,
                "value": "issue" 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ticket_id": 15178,
        "status": "solved",
        "custom_fields": [
            {
                "id": 360015283851,
                "value": "severity_3"
            },
            {
                "id": 360016758872,
                "value": "request"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Using the following code I am able to flatten the nested array, but the output gives me 4 records instead of initial 2:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

# Read CSV from file
with open('./testcase.json') as f:
  d = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data=d, record_path='custom_fields', meta=['ticket_id','status'])

df.to_json('testcase-out.json',orient='records')
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 360015283851,
        "status": "solved",
        "ticket_id": 15177,
        "value": "severity_2"
    },
    {
        "id": 360016758872,
        "status": "solved",
        "ticket_id": 15177,
        "value": "issue"
    },
    {
        "id": 360015283851,
        "status": "solved",
        "ticket_id": 15178,
        "value": "severity_3"
    },
    {
        "id": 360016758872,
        "status": "solved",
        "ticket_id": 15178,
        "value": "request"
    }
]

             id       value ticket_id  status
0  360015283851  severity_2     15177  solved
1  360016758872       issue     15177  solved
2  360015283851  severity_3     15178  solved
3  360016758872     request     15178  solved
```

I would prefer something like this:
Keep the 2 records and create columns from the nested objects.

```
[
    {
        "custom_field_id_360015283851": "severity_2",
        "custom_field_id_360016758872": "issue",
        "status": "solved",
        "ticket_id": 15177
    },
    {
        "custom_field_id_360015283851": "severity_3",
        "custom_field_id_360016758872": "request",
        "status": "solved",
        "ticket_id": 15178
    }
]
```

Is it possible to keep the number or records or somehow merge it after?

EDIT:
The following works, but its static and probably not elegant. But works...

```
# create new columns based on the custom field values
df['cf_360015283851'] = np.where(df['id'] == 360015283851, df['value'], '')
df['cf_360016758872'] = np.where(df['id'] == 360016758872, df['value'], '')

# delete columns from the custom values
del df['id']
del df['value']

# merge the lines where ticket_id is the same
df = df.replace('',np.nan, regex=True)
df1 = df.groupby('ticket_id',as_index=False,sort=False).last()
```

Output:

```
   ticket_id  status cf_360015283851 cf_360016758872
0      15177  solved      severity_2           issue
1      15178  solved      severity_3         request
```

Comment: `json_normalize` is a nice tool... when the json data is consistant with what it can process. If it is too complex, better to revert to the good old `json` module, and then process the lists and dictionaries by hand with some Python code.

Answer (score 2):

You could directly process the json file with the `json` module and direct Python processing. But as you have already started with Pandas, you could just pivot your current dataframe:

```
df.pivot(index=['ticket_id', 'status'], columns='id', values='value')
```

it give immediately:

```
id               360015283851 360016758872
ticket_id status                          
15177     solved   severity_2        issue
15178     solved   severity_3      request
```

Comment: That works, but `df.to_json('testcase-out.json',orient='records')` is not generating the file correctly.

Comment: @Jerry: you probably need to reset the index first: `df.reset_index().to_json(...)`

Comment: that was it. Thank you (sorry, I am complete beginner)